# Why jsonp in Angular always returns a 404 error as status?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When if the server gives back various error (like 400, 403 etc.), I always get a 404 from the jsonp call results (in the error branch i mean)... is this an intended behaviour? How to get the real error code as the browser console does? I.e., 400 for 400, 500 for 500, and not always 404?

Here is my code (please replace YOUR_LINK_HERE with any link you would like to test):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularApp">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

      <title>Boxkeeply</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
     angular.module('angularApp', [])

     .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

          var JsonURI = "YOUR_LINK_HERE?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

          $http.jsonp(JsonURI).
              success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data.httpResponse.statusCode==200){
                  alert("success!")


                }
                else{


                }
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {       
                alert("error code: "+status)
            });      
      });

     </script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advace!

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6jf33/

Comment: Mmh no it doesn't... I know that the success branch works well, but it is the error one that gives problems

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, 403, 500 errors can't fulfill request therefore you don't get status code back. Check this document on protocols errors
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4

Comment: Thank you! So there is no any javascript way to know the exact error code like browsers do?

Comment: That's correct, for those errors you will get status: 0